# I am trying to setup bCNC and can't open the ./dev/attyACM0 port

Tags: permissions, serial-port

I've added myself to the dialout group and run

```
getent group dialout
```

and it returns

```
dialout:x:20:myUserName
```

I try to access the serial port and am getting...

```
[Errno 13] could not open port
/dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 13]
Permission denied '/dev/attyACM0'
```

So clearly I've left a step out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to log out and log in for the group changes to apply. (other solutions might be possible)

Lets walk trough this. I am currently not member of `dialout`

```
getent group dialout
dialout:x:20:
```

Now I add myself

```
sudo usermod -aG dialout myUser
```

and verify

```
getent group dialout
dialout:x:20:myUser
```

However `getent` just looks at the configuration not at the current state (which is not updated). You can see this by looking at `groups`

```
groups
myUser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
```

no `dialout` here. After relogin it will work